# How to Fix the Corner Collapsing on Hover Out /Scaling Down CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to test some boxes with Transform Scale Property but facing a little issue.When i hover the box it works perfect without collapsing with the other boxes edges and on hover out the right edge/side of left box collapse.
Here is the code below:

```css
.fond{position:absolute;padding-top:85px;top:0;left:0; right:0;bottom:0;
 background-color:#00506b;}

.style_prevu_kit
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:0;
    width:196px;
    height:210px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1); 
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1);   

}
.style_prevu_kit:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);   
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div align="center" class="fond">
<div style="width:1000px;">

<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#cb2025;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#f8b334;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#97bf0d;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#00a096;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#93a6a8;"></div>


<div style=" padding:5px; color:#b5e6e3; font-weight:300; font-size:30px; font-family:'Roboto';padding-top:20px;">CSS <font style="font-weight:400;">HOVER</font></div>
        <a href="http://www.wifeo.com/code" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><div style="  color:#b5e6e3; font-weight:300; font-size:20px; font-family:'Roboto';">www.wifeo.com/code</div></a>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transist `z-index` as well, and since `z-index` changes in whole numbers you need to use more than 1 step, or else it will change to fast.

*A side note, you don't have to repeat the `transition` in both rules, and no point to use `transform: scale(1)` as it doesn't do anything*

```css
.fond{position:absolute;padding-top:85px;top:0;left:0; right:0;bottom:0;
 background-color:#00506b;}

.style_prevu_kit
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:0;
    width:196px;
    height:210px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in,
                box-shadow 200ms ease-in,
                z-index 200ms;
}
.style_prevu_kit:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div align="center" class="fond">
<div style="width:1000px;">

<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#cb2025;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#f8b334;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#97bf0d;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#00a096;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#93a6a8;"></div>


<div style=" padding:5px; color:#b5e6e3; font-weight:300; font-size:30px; font-family:'Roboto';padding-top:20px;">CSS <font style="font-weight:400;">HOVER</font></div>
        <a href="http://www.wifeo.com/code" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><div style="  color:#b5e6e3; font-weight:300; font-size:20px; font-family:'Roboto';">www.wifeo.com/code</div></a>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man that's what i was looking for.in hover state you used z-index:10 and in normal z-index-1 .Thanks.